# Identify docker hostname is passed or generated

Tags: docker

When starting a container, if we pass a hostname with -h option, container will set its hostname to that. If no -h option is provided, container generates a random hostname

How can I enforce that my container is always started with -h parameter so I never end up with a randomly generated hostname?

Is there any other way to get host server's hostname inside container?

Comment: The hostname inside the container almost never matters.  Why do you need it?

Comment: (The single exception I can think of is RabbitMQ, which stores state in a directory after the hostname; if you don't manually specify `-h`, it will misplace its state on restart even if volumes are configured correctly, but there's no particular protection against this.)

Comment: My service running in container, sends a URL to the clients that the clients can talk to. To guarantee that service sends a good url to the client, I take in the container hostname as a parameter and use that to form URLs.

Comment: An environment variable might be easier to configure; it will also be easier to check if it hasn't been set at all.